# The passed action type is invalid - ROS2 foxy

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, i'm trying to use ros2 action send_goal ( so i can send a goal to a server node ) and i don't know the Yaml format to write the goal so i can use this command. i tried too many ways but it didn't work.
Please can you help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400905/the-passed-action-type-is-invalid---ros2-foxy/) by [ohmimi](https://answers.ros.org/users/102097/ohmimi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2022-05-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-05-19**:
It would help if you could tell the action type you are trying to send. Also, have you seen [this tutorial](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Understanding-ROS2-Actions.html#ros2-action-send-goal)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for your help, i discovered the yaml format to write the goal argument  "{order : 10}".
and also i forgot to source after opening a new terminal.

---

Originally posted by [ohmimi](https://answers.ros.org/users/102097/ohmimi/) with karma: 26 on 2022-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1